# objective-c : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d75720

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am creating a Linked List in C and I am getting an error upon addition (and also a warning).

Both of which are written below.

I have tried a few things to no avail...any advice would be amazing.

[it is a linked list with a max size!]

```
//in the tester
XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head.next);
```

throws this error

```
 failed: ((testList.head.next) != nil) failed: throwing "-[__NSCFNumber next]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d75720"
```

this is the add method

```
- (void)add:(NSObject *)node {
    Node *newNode = [[Node alloc] init];
    if (self.head)
        newNode.next = self.head;
    else
        self.head = newNode;
    self.num_nodes++;
}
 

NList *testList = [[NList alloc] initWithSize:2];
```

gives a warning

Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')

This is the constructor

```
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger size;

.....

- (id) initWithSize:(NSInteger *)size {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.head = nil;
        self.size = *size;
        self.num_nodes = 0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/SpW75Pf0

## edit

```
- (void)testAdd
{
    NList *testList = [[NList alloc] initWithSize:2];
    NSObject *testNodeOne =  @1;
    [testList add:(testNodeOne)];
    XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head);
    NSObject *testNodeTwo =  @3;

    [testList add:testNodeTwo];
    XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head);
    XCTAssertNotNil(testList.head.next);

}
```

head.next throws the error

```
/LinkedListTest.m: test failure: -[LinkedListTest testAdd] failed: ((testList.head.next) != nil) failed: throwing "-[__NSCFNumber next]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d75720"
```

=c

Comment: the first tells that `testList.head` returns `NSCFNumber` and it don't have property named `next`

Comment: Just so you know if you don't share all you code no one will help. I can't access pastebin so I will not help, it's that simple. Also this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `-initWithSize:` method takes a pointer to an `NSInteger`, but you are trying to pass in an `NSInteger` rather than a pointer to one. There's no reason for the method to take a pointer, since `NSIntegers` fit on the stack and you aren't changing its value. The method signature should probably be:

```
-(id) initWithSize:(NSInteger)size
```

(and of course, you should have `self.size = size;` inside the method). That will fix the warning you're getting.

As for the assertion - it looks like you're hitting the end of the list. Since you didn't include the code surrounding the assertion, it's impossible to tell why you're getting a nil `next` pointer.

Comment: I have the code on the pastebin link! also when I do what you said now I Get ...types in implementation of 'initWithSize:': 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') vs 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') by the method declaration of the constructor!

Comment: If you don't post your code here, others won't be able to make sense of this question and answer in the future. As for the warning, you have to change the method prototype, too, of course. It sounds like you missed that step.

Comment: okay! I added the assertion code! you were right about the method prototype. I checked there but I didn't notice the problem..I guess it's time to sleep, not code.. wah. Mind helping more with the other error?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that you're not doing the insert properly. Are you trying to insert in the front or back of the list in the `-add` method? If the front, then your code is incomplete. You need to not only set `newNode.next` to `self.head`, you also need to set `self.head` to `newNode`. If you want it in the back, then you need to set `self.head.next` to `newNode`.